# getting error : Server terminated early with status 127 in selenium chrome driver

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js, selenium-chromedriver, chai

When I try to do unit test with chrome driver, I am getting error : `Server terminated early with status 127`, I have installed chrome driver still getting error. Can anyone please help me why I am getting this issue. Here is my code ,

```
let webdriver = require("selenium-webdriver");
        let chromeOptions = new chrome.Options();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("test-type");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("start-maximized");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--js-flags=--expose-gc");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--enable-precise-memory-info");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-default-apps");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-infobars");

        driver = new webdriver.Builder()
          .forBrowser("chrome")
          .setChromeOptions(chromeOptions)
          .build();
```

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was missing a Java Runtime environment (JRE). I’m running e2e tests with Selenium in a Debian-based docker image, hence `sudo apt-get install default-jre` did the trick for me. It’s a pity selenium doesn’t give a more useful error message in this case.

Follow the steps :-

1. `apt-get install default-jre`
2. `apt-get -f install` for a fix install
3. `apt-get install chromium-browser` Make sure to install the correct version of chrome related to your chromedriver, e.g. chrome 60-62 for chromedriver 2.33
4. Config webdriver to start chrome in ‘headless’ mode, as to avoid other unnecessary dependencies. In node it looks like:

   `const options = new chromeDriver.Options();`

   `options.addArguments(
   'headless',
   'disable-gpu',
   );`

   `new webdriver.Builder()
   .forBrowser('chrome')
   .setChromeOptions(options)
   .build();`

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody here is trying to run a headless chromium instance on an Azure vm, you'll need:

- Java JRE (apt: java-common)
- Chromium -- even if the dependencies in your code include it (apt: chromium-chromedriver)

Alternatively (for the virtual environment), you can [set up xvfb as described here](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/38-headless). But, you'll save yourself a lot of time if you just install the apt.

I spent a few hours here figuring this out until it worked, hope it helps somebody in the future.

My specific use case was a Node.js server running on an Azure instance (I think a b2ms? machine size .. it's $15/mo) running Ubuntu 18.04 which queries websites of interest for certain keywords every minute or so